# Content type image/png ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My server request is returning image/png content type header. Server link is like this: `http://locahost/PrintView?locate=12,12`

My browser is showing image successful.

But I need to get image via ajax call. But ajax result is coming encoded format.

[image]

So I can not appent it to html img or another element.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:7741/PrintView/Crop",
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: { "locate":param },            
        success: function (response) {
           $('#crop').html('<img src="' + response + '" />');
           console.log(response)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: That "encoded" format is "PNG"

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to load an image from a GET request. There is absolutely no reason to complicate things by involving Ajax here.

```
$('#crop').empty().append(
    $("<img />").attr(
        "src", 
        "http://localhost:7741/PrintView/Crop?locate=" + encodeURIComponent(param)
    )
);
```

Comment: How can I get an image with ajax get request? Is this possible? Should I change server code?

Comment: @bookmarker — The code you have in the question is getting the image with Ajax. Your problem is that (having got the image) you are trying to treat it as if it was a URL, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that image with ajax request, you should first encode it with base64 and response to ajax request with a base64 string.